# Why are higher order functions preferred over for-loops for iteration?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

In [this JavaScript style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#iterators-and-generators) it suggests that **dealing with pure functions that return values is easier to reason about than side-effects**. Aside from that, is there any performance benefits to using higher order functions like [array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for iteration? as opposed to looping?

Comment: Unless you're writing something like a high-performance game engine, the performance differences are irrelevant compared to the code maintenance differences.

Comment: Don't use `map()` for iteration, use it for mapping - which yes, does involve iteration, but isn't a logical replacement for the generic iteration of a for loop. Use `forEach()` for iteration. (Lately I keep seeing code that uses `. map()` but ignores its return value, which makes the code *harder* to understand rather than easier.)